# South migration files empty with populated models.py file

Tags: python, django, django-south

I have been south for a long time now, and yesterday i duplicated a project where i am using database routers to divide my databases. The only thing that has been changed in my code is the database name, but i'm afraid that i may be using the wrong commands to migrate. I ran the initial schemamigration and migrated which created the databases (default and exercises), afterwards i added two new models which were not initialized by south.

In desperation i deleted the south table from the default table and the directory with the migrations.

Please note that the database is already populated with tables!

And a sample of my models:

```
class MuscleGroupName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(null=False)
    link = models.CharField(null=True)

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'exercise_db'
        db_table = 'musclegroupname'
```

## Commands:

```
./manage.py syncdb
Syncing...
Creating tables ...
Creating table south_migrationhistory
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > django_admin_bootstrapped
 > django.contrib.admin
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > django_verbatim
 > rest_framework
 > south
 > Exercise

Not synced (use migrations):
 - 
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)

./manage.py schemamigration Exercise --initial
Creating migrations directory at '/Exercise/migrations'...
Creating __init__.py in '/Exercise/migrations'...
Created 0001_initial.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migrate Exercise

./manage.py migrate Exercise 
Running migrations for Exercise:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > Exercise:0001_initial
 - Loading initial data for Exercise.
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)
```

At this point the `0001_initial.py` file is pretty much empty, theres no models or anything:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from south.utils import datetime_utils as datetime
from south.db import db
from south.v2 import SchemaMigration
from django.db import models


class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):
        pass

    def backwards(self, orm):
        pass

    models = {

    }

    complete_apps = ['Exercise']
```

## Source code:

```
# settings.py
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['Exercise.router.DatabaseAppsRouter']
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING = {'exercise_db': 'exercises',}
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'special2_django',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '8889',
    },
    'exercises': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'special2_exercise',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock',   # Or an IP Address that your DB is hosted on
        'PORT': '8889',
    }     
}

# router.py
class DatabaseAppsRouter(object): 
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """"Point all read operations to the specific database."""
        if settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.has_key(model._meta.app_label):
            return settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING[model._meta.app_label]
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        """Point all write operations to the specific database."""
        if settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.has_key(model._meta.app_label):
            return settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING[model._meta.app_label]
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        """Allow any relation between apps that use the same database."""
        db_obj1 = settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.get(obj1._meta.app_label)
        db_obj2 = settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.get(obj2._meta.app_label)
        if db_obj1 and db_obj2:
            if db_obj1 == db_obj2:
                return True
            else:
                return False
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        """Make sure that apps only appear in the related database."""
        if db in settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.values():
            return settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.get(model._meta.app_label) == db
        elif settings.DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING.has_key(model._meta.app_label):
            return False
        return None
```

## UPDATE:

When i remove `app_label` it detects the classes in my model, so i think something is wrong with my router?! For the sake of sanity i have to mention that this code is working in my previous project that is running!

Comment: Late comment, but I had the same symptom (empty migration file). It was a brand new project added to our existing database, the models were in separte files inside app/models/.  When I added the (default) `app_label` it found my models, which leads me to think that you need to use the app_label when you call `schemamigration --initial`..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `south` from `INSTALLED_APPS`, delete all `migration` folders, `syncdb` again.

Then add `south` back to `INSTALLED_APPS` and apply the initial fake migration.

Comment: If i add south again, i need to run `syncdb` else the history table does not exist in the default database. Should i run syncdb again after i add south back? That gets me back to my previous problem.

Comment: Oh you did not mention that i should delete the table. Anyhow i did as you said. Added back `south` ran `manage.py schemamigration Exercise --initial` followed by `manage.py migrate Exercise --fake`. But the migration files are still empty and the new models are not added.

Comment: After you add `south` back, do a `syncdb` to add south tables. Then, since your app tables are already there, you should create a fake migration using

`/manage.py migrate myapp 0001 --fake`. See here for more info -- http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html#converting-an-app

Comment: I have tried this already, but the new model entries never get detected and added?

Comment: Try this right after `syncdb`. `./manage.py convert_to_south myapp`

Comment: When i do syncdb and the `convert_to_south` i just get: `This application has no models; this command is for applications that already have models syncdb'd.`

Comment: I tried the other method you mentioned with the fake migration, but when will it create the additional models? The migration files are still empty though.

Comment: Do you have models in the app you're trying to convert to south?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58451/discussion-between-javacake-and-ashish-kasturia).

Comment: I have updated my post, please check the new discovery.

Comment: I think you're better off asking the question in one of the South's google groups. Sorry, I couldn't be of much help.

Comment: Ashish, i gave up and went back to one database instead, i'm lacking time :o) But thanks ALOT of trying, i really appreciate that. I will post on south unless Django 1.7 migration will become more robust till' then.

Comment: Sorry to hear that you didn't find a resolution. Also, no problem.